# How to access variable from init()

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using datatables to show some info using ajax.

```
// Setup module
var DatatableAdvanced = function() {

    // Basic Datatable examples
    var _componentDatatableAdvanced = function() {
        // Ajax DataTable
        var ajaxTable = $('.datatable-ajax');
        var table = ajaxTable.data("table");
        var search = ajaxTable.data("search");   

        ajaxTable.DataTable({
            autoWidth: false,
            dom: '<"datatable-header"Bip><"datatable-scroll-wrap"rt><"datatable-footer"ip>',
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ordering: true,
            ajax: table + ".php?action=ajaxTable&" + search,
        });
    };

    return {
        init: function() {
            _componentDatatableAdvanced();
        }
    }
}();
```

Initialize code:

```
// Initialize modules
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    DatatableAdvanced.init();

    // Ajax inline view
    $('.table.ajax-view').on( "click", ".ajax-view-info", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        /*var test = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
        test.append('hello');*/
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = DatatableAdvanced.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }

    });
});
```

How can I access ajaxTable after running DatatableAdvanced.init(); I want to update the table with more info when the users clicks on the 'ajax-view-info' button. However DatatableAdvanced.row(tr) gives an error not a function

Comment: `$('.datatable-ajax')` should get the same object that you store in the variable `ajaxTable `. The variable is a DOM object so it seems reasonable to just go get it again. Or you can return it from your function if you'd prefer

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it by placing

```
var viewTable = null
```

before

```
var DatatableAdvanced = function() {...
```

then using

```
viewTable = ajaxTable.DataTable({
```

inside the function. Now viewTable can be accessed anywhere